# Data is not getting updated in the view after promise is resolved

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, promise, slim

I am using my Rails app as an API backend. So I have a single page angular app which will make multiple api calls and start displaying as each data gets returned. I don't want to wait for all the results from the API call and then load the data, so I started learning deferred and promise.

I have an angular service called **api** where I will have $http calls to all my api. I have hardcoded the data that returns from each one of the api calls for testing purposes.

```
debugger.factory "api", ["$resource", "$q", ($resource, $q) ->
  apiCall1 = [
    key1: "v1"
    key2: "v2"
    key3: "v3"
  ]

  apiCall2 =
  .
  .
  .
  apiCall7 =

  factory = getIsDynamicApp: ->
    deferred = $q.defer()
    deferred.resolve apiCall1
    deferred.promise

  factory
]
```

I have created an edge service to call methods from my api service. I have used $timeout to simulate the async api calls.

```
debugger.factory "EdgeService", ($resource, api, $q, $timeout, $http) ->

  fetchIsDynamic = ->
    api.getIsDynamicApp()   

  tickets: ->
    deferred = $q.defer()
    fetchIsDynamic().then (data) ->
      $timeout (->
        deferred.resolve data
        console.log data #<- this works, I can see the data
      ), 3000  
    deferred.promise
```

In my EdgeController I call the service and attach the value to $scope.data

```
debugger.controller "EdgeController", ($scope, EdgeService) ->
  $scope.load = ->
    $scope.data = EdgeService.tickets()

debugger.$inject = ["$scope"]
```

This is my slim template

```
doctype html
html(ng-app="debugger" class="ng-scope")
  head
    title Ads Debugger
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application/debugger"
    = javascript_include_tag "debugger"

  body
    #content(ng-controller="EdgeController")
      .search_form
        form class="serch_form"
          input type="text" name="search_box" id="search_box"
          input type="submit" value="Search" ng-click="load()"

      div
        pre message {{data}}
```

The output is not getting binded'

[image]

**Also is this the best way to implement if I have to make multiple api calls and update the view as each one returns?**

Comment: I recommend providing examples in JS, and/or a plnkr or fiddle:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$scope.data = EdgeService.tickets()
```

Should be

```
EdgeService.tickets().then (data) ->
 $scope.data = data
```

AngularJS does not automatically unwrap promises [in newer versions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#templates-no-longer-automatically-unwrap-promises). This would work in older versions of Angular.

To do multiple API calls dependant of one another you can do

```
callA
.then(callB)
.then(callC)
```

Yo can do multiple in parallell using $q.all

```
$q.all([callA, callB, callC]).then( .... )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Also I am planing on making data an array and push the values into the array after each call. Is this the best way ?

Comment: My api calls are not dependent on one other. $q.all will wait for all the api calls to return promise and then do something. But I want to update my view as I get the results. One of my api calls takes 1 mins so i cant wait so long to show the other values.