# How can I update the view after each API call

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and I am building an app where I want to make multiple API calls and update the view as the data from them comes by. I do not want to wait for all the api calls to be completed to update my view and my api calls are not dependent on each other. Some of the API calls takes more than a minute to return the data.

I was thinking of using **$q.all** since I can start multiple asynchronous tasks, but I can't update the view after each one is completed. Could someone please point out how I can build this ?

Should I just use $scope.$apply in the success block of my $http call ?
My progress so far [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481327/data-is-not-getting-updated-in-the-view-after-promise-is-resolved/20481472?noredirect=1#20481472) (this was different issue I had, but the code is the same)

Comment: You could do to improve your question, show some code samples or a JSFiddle to better explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: your questions are far too vague and you have provided no code....create a demo in plunker that helps identify your issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand your model and what you're trying to achieve from you question, but you might want to use something like `$broadcast()` and `$on()`.

So you'd broadcast an event when you're API has finished downloading:

```
$scope.$broadcast('API-download', data);
```

and then listen for it elsewhere and update your view

```
$scope.$on(
    'API-download',
    function(data){ 
         processData( data );
    }
)
```

That syntax might not be perfect, and as you have multiple API calls you'll need to broadcast different events like 'API-product-download' and 'API-catalogue-download'