# Scope not updating in the view after promise is resolved

Tags: angularjs

Even though there is a similar question for this [Data is not getting updated in the view after promise is resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481327/data-is-not-getting-updated-in-the-view-after-promise-is-resolved) but I am already using this approach and the view is not being updated.

I have a factory:

```js
'use strict';

myApp
.factory('Factory1', [ '$http','$q','$location', '$rootScope', 'Service', function($http, $q, $location, $rootScope, Service){

    return {

        checkSomething: function(data){

          var deferred = $q.defer();  //init promise

          Service.checkSomething(data,function(response){
                // This is a response from a get request from a service
                deferred.resolve(response);
          });

          return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

I have a controller:

```js
'use strict';

myApp
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location','Service', 'Factory1' function($rootScope, $scope, $location, Service, Factory1) {


    if(Service.someCheck() !== undefined)
    {
      // Setting the variable when view is loaded for the first time, but this shouldn't effect anything
      $scope.stringToDisplay = "Loaded";

    }


    $scope.clickMe = function(){
      Factory1.chechSomething($scope.inputData).then(function(response){
          $scope.stringToDisplay = response.someData; // The data here is actually being loaded!

      });
    };

}]);
```

And the view:

```html
<div class="app " ng-controller="MyCtrl">    
    {{stringToDisplay}}    
    <button class="button" ng-click="clickMe()">Update display</button>    
</div>
```

**But the data is not being updated in the view when I click on a button "Update display". Why?**

Even though the `$scope` is being loaded with the data

EDIT:

Hm, it seems that I am getting a error when I try `$scope.$apply()` and it says:

```
[$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This might be a digest cycle issue. You could try:

```
...
$scope.stringToDisplay = response.someData;
$scope.$apply();
...
```

For the sake of completeness, [here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) is a nice wrap-up of `$scope.$apply`.

**Edit:** I tried to reproduce the error in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57b7g/), but cannot seem to find any issues. It works flawlessly without `$scope.$apply`. I use `setTimeout` in order to simulate asynchronous operations, which should not trigger a digest cycle by itself.

Comment: hmm, adding a `$scope.$apply();` didn't work :/ , I will try another approach

Comment: hm x 2 it says  `$digest already in progress` when I try an apply

Comment: I see. Interestingly enough, I cannot reproduce the issue [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57b7g/).

Comment: interesting. Maybe the problem is that I am using `apply` on some other place and it is complaining when I try to do the same here. The fiddle is quite interesting and very helpful. I will look into it and get back to you a little later. + for the nice fiddle

Comment: You're welcome. In fact, I am surprised that using `setTimeout` does not require us to call `$apply`.

Comment: Yes, I have read about that. Using a timeout is a suggested way when using `digest` as it will apply the scope automatically, but I haven't tested that just yet. Thanks again for excellent fiddle. I believe it will come in handy to other people as well :)

Comment: Did it fix your problem? If so, I would adjust the answer accordingly. Otherwise the current answer might be misleading, since the actual answer is hidden somewhere in the comments.

Comment: I haven't, but yet the problem might be in a use of $apply method that I have been using on other parts of the application, so I have to clean them first. To post the whole code would be a bit outside the scope of the question. What you have showed in the `fiddle` answers my question perfectly. If it is working like that is the perfect answer for me as a proof of concept and that is what I was looking for. I just need to update my code around it in the application as well. This is so much helpful for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your function

```
$scope.clickMe =$scope.$apply(function(){
      Factory1.chechSomething($scope.inputData).then(function(response){
          $scope.stringToDisplay = response.someData; // The data here is actually being loaded!

      });
    });
```

Comment: if I add `$scope.$apply` I can't even click a button :) but I have tried `function(){$scope.$apply( //inside code)}` but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Aleks, I am having same issue here, did you solve it?